# Command for keeping the lines with a certain length in a file

Tags: text-processing

I would like to keep the lines with exactly 639 characters in my .txt file. What is the command to do so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep -E '^.{639}$' your.txt
```

The `^` and `$` match beginning and end of line. The `.{639}` match any character exactly 639 times.

As Stéphane commented, this can be shortened (by one character) to:

```
grep -Ex '.{639}' your.txt
```

with `-x` indicating: `Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line`

Comment: @Student If this solves your problem, please consider accepting this answer by clicking the ✔ (checkmark) next to the answer. That is the way other people know your problem has been solved. If a better answer comes along, you can always change the accepted answer.

Comment: Or just `grep -Ex '.{639}'`

Comment: Never bury in obscure, tool dependant options what can be expressed in standard language features.

Comment: @user1663987, `-x` is [specified in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html); if that's "obscure" to you, you would be well advised to study through the entirety of `man man` and learn to use it.  ;)

Comment: It can be obscure if it is a seldom used option which implements commonly known operators.

Answer (score 12):

using awk:

```
awk 'length == 639'
```

or slightly more understandable:

```
awk 'length() == 639'
```

---

\thanks{@fedorqui}

Comment: From `man awk`: _There is one feature of historical AWK implementations that gawk supports: It is possible to call the `length()` built-in function not only with no argument, but even without parentheses!_ But then, _Using  this  feature is poor practice, and gawk issues a warning about its use if --lint is specified on the command line._ Even though it works, to me, this is quite misleading.

Comment: perhaps `awk 'length() == 639'` ?

Comment: To me, this is way more understandable : )

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc 'v/\v^.{639}$/d' -cx file.txt
```

1. `\v` turn on magic
2. `^.{639}$` find lines of exactly 639 characters
3. `v` invert selection
4. `d` delete
5. `x` save and close

Answer (score -1):

You haven't said what your data is, or whether its acceptable to break up words in the middle.   So here's an alternative that may suit written text better.

```
export MANWIDTH=639
cat file.txt | man -l -
```

This will use your default pager to display, or you pipe the output to something else.